# PIP error : cannot build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try to install sip with pip, it shows an error. The full output was :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting sip
  Using cached sip-6.5.0.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: toml in c:\users\Admin\appdata\roaming\python\pyt
hon310-32\site-packages (from sip) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\python310-32\lib\s
ite-packages (from sip) (57.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\Admin\appdata\roaming\pytho
n\python310-32\site-packages (from sip) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\Admin\appdat
a\roaming\python\python310-32\site-packages (from packaging->sip) (3.0.6)
Building wheels for collected packages: sip
```

It was running perfectly. But;

```
  Building wheel for sip (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Program Files\Python310-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\R
oaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_proce
ss.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbp29upup'
       cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-z5zff4sm\sip_b8fe66d11
90b4a5bb4ab29314f68ed38
  Complete output (147 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\abstract_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\abstract_project.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\api.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\argument_parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\bindings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\buildable.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\configurable.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\distutils_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\helpers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\installable.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\project.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\pyproject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\py_versions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\setuptools_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  copying sipbuild\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\distinfo
  copying sipbuild\distinfo\distinfo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\distinf
o
  copying sipbuild\distinfo\main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\distinfo
  copying sipbuild\distinfo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\distinf
o
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module
  copying sipbuild\module\abi_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module

  copying sipbuild\module\main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module
  copying sipbuild\module\module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module
  copying sipbuild\module\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\tools
  copying sipbuild\tools\build.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\tools
  copying sipbuild\tools\install.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\tools
  copying sipbuild\tools\sdist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\tools
  copying sipbuild\tools\wheel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\tools
  copying sipbuild\tools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\tools
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module\source
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\apiversions.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbui
ld\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\array.h -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\bool.cpp -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\descriptors.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbui
ld\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sip
build\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuil
d\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuil
d\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\objmap.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbu
ild\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\qtlib.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\README.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\m
odule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuil
d\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\setup.py.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
\module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.h.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\
module\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\sipint.h -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\siplib.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\threads.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\m
odule\source\12
  copying sipbuild\module\source\12\voidptr.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\m
odule\source\12
  creating build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\array.h -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\bool.cpp -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\descriptors.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbui
ld\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\int_convertors.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sip
build\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL2 -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuil
d\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\LICENSE-GPL3 -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuil
d\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\MANIFEST.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\objmap.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\pyproject.toml -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbu
ild\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\README.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\m
odule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.cfg.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuil
d\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\setup.py.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild
\module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.h.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mod
ule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sip.rst.in -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\
module\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\sipint.h -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\siplib.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\mo
dule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\threads.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\m
odule\source\13
  copying sipbuild\module\source\13\voidptr.c -> build\lib.win32-3.10\sipbuild\m
odule\source\13
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pip\_
vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pip\_
vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310-32\site-packages\pip\_
vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 49, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 155, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_ext
ensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_ex
tensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 202, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 528, in build_ext
ension
      objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 327, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 224, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-py_mvk7m\overlay\Lib\s
ite-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  setuptools._distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0
 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visual
studio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sip
Failed to build sip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for sip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Can you please help me find the problem.
I wrote this ( line copied from https://pypi.org/project/sip/ ) :

```
pip install sip
```

OS : Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro [Version 6.3.9600]

Python Version: 3.10.0

PIP Version: 21.3.1

Comment: Please provide more details about the exact commands you ran and what the full output was, as well as more details about your environment (OS, Python version, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried installing sip in a venv, and it went smoothly. I guess you need to upgrade pip:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

and then run again the installation script:

`pip install sip`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

careful reading is the key ->

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0
 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visual
studio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35117308)

Answer (score -1):

Run the command in the script directory on this path C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts

I founded that method on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVfvLYM2Yes&ab_channel=MustufaBaig

This method worked for me.